# how to bind interface object to tweet object in c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am have a method (GetUser()), method return type is an interface (IUser) and I have a class (User) include same fields with IUser. I want to bind GetUser methods result to User object.
I am using c#.

**Method :**

```
 IEnumerable<IUser> GetUser();
```

**Interface :**

```
public interface IUser {

     public string Id{ get; set;} 
     public string Name{ get; set;}
     public string Username{ get; set;}
     public IAddress Address{ get; set;}
     //And more fields
}
```

**Class :**

```
public class User {

     public string Id{ get; set;} 
     public string Name{ get; set;}
     public string Username{ get; set;}
     public Address Address{ get; set;}
     //And more fields
}
```

> *I tried the following cases and not works.*

```
IEnumerable<User> user = AnyLibrary.GetUser() as IEnumerable<User>;

IEnumerable<User> user = (IEnumerable<User>) AnyLibrary.GetUser();
```

Is it possible and how can i do this ?

Comment: Your user class should inherit from IUser - `public class User : IUser`

Comment: Inherit `User` from `IUser`, this is not golang, it has to be explicit.

Comment: Note also that `Address` also needs to inherit from `IAddress`, etc

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Go has implicit inheritance? Interesting

Comment: It's not implicit inheritance, it's called Structural Typing.

Comment: @stuartd IUser model is in the library and i want to map this data in my databese with User class. it is not possible to inherit from IUser because it in a external library

Comment: _"it is not possible to inherit from IUser because it in a external library"_ - classes can inherit from interfaces in external libraries, eg my code can inherit from an interface defined in the framework libraries, so not sure what you mean here?

Comment: @AdamVincent thanks for the clarification. That reminded me I had come across this before, in [Type System Differences in TypeScript (Structural Type System) VS C# & Java (Nominal Type System)](https://www.triplet.fi/blog/type-system-differences-in-typescript-structural-type-system-vs-c-java-nominal-type-system/) - not something I know much about RN, so always good to get a reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

The real solution to the problem is to inherit the IUser class as Adam Vincent and stuartd mentioned.

But If don't want to inherit from the Iuser class.Another solution that comes to my mind json serialize to GetUser() method's result and deserialize to User object.

```
string users = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AnyLibrary.GetUser());
IEnumerable<User> c_user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<User>>(users);
```

This solutions works for me well.